# mr-auto class of bootstrap not working as excepted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

```css
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav **mr-auto**">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="homepage.aspx">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Terms</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton4" runat="server">View Books</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">User Login</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Sign Up</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton3" runat="server">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton7" runat="server">Hello user</asp:LinkButton>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

[See the navigation there is some margin left between the logo and the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZJuw.png)

I imported this code form bootstrap but the first  is not totally aligning left but the second  is rightly aligned to the right hand side[see I have inspected this but it looks fine to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHUas.png)

Comment: please confirm which version of Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation of Flex of Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/):

> Apply display utilities to create a flexbox container and transform direct children elements into flex items. Flex containers and items are able to be modified further with additional flex properties.

To enable this behavior you need to add one of the below `d-flex` classes to the container element, which in your case is the root `div` element:

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

Valid options are:

```
.d-flex
.d-inline-flex
.d-sm-flex
.d-sm-inline-flex
.d-md-flex
.d-md-inline-flex
.d-lg-flex
.d-lg-inline-flex
.d-xl-flex
.d-xl-inline-flex
```